# Javascript this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the href from a tag releted to that div.
I'm having html structure like

```
    <div>
     <a>
     <button>
    </div>
```

Above structure in for loop, having different urls in href.

I want something like when I clicked on 1st button inside 1st div i want url in href of that div.
When I clicked on 2nd div button I want url in href of 2nd div.

How do I achieve that.

Comment: start with some javascript ... use addEventListener ...

Comment: You want the href where?  For what purpose?

Comment: `$("button").click(function() { console.log($(this).closest("div").find("a").attr("href")) });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to give the button a `class` and add `event listner`

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
buttons.forEach(button => {
  console.log(button)
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const button = e.target;
    const href = button.parentNode.querySelector('a').href;
    alert(href)
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
     <a href="https://www.google.com">google link</a>
     <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
<div>
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com">facebook link</a>
     <button class="button">facebook</button>
</div>
<div>
     <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">yahoo link</a>
     <button class="button">yahoo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the selector, I just update it.

Comment: Thanks it works. But can u help to find the a tag if it's like section - div - section - div - a - button

Comment: I'm happy that it worked for you, could you provide the HTML code?